# React Material UI- NativeSelect Dropdown menu style customize

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

We used `NativeSelect` components in our existing projects.
And now we need to change the style of `NativeSelect` box dropdown Menu.
If we use Select, we can solve this easily using `MenuProps`.
But in NativeSelect we can use `<option>` only, not use `MenuProps`, and `MenuItem`.
How can I change the style of `NativeSelect` Dropdown Menu to follow our design?

Comment: How about adding your code so that we could understand your problem better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use styled-components.

npm install --save styled-components

https://styled-components.com/

also you can change in MenuProps

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve it by using styled-components here.
https://styled-components.com/

Comment: Thanks, Jin. Attached url is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Generally we can use styledcomponents.
We can fix this styling using styled components, so if we cover components using styled components, then this isn't issue.

import styled from "styled-components";